# Is magento model load do select for update

Tags: model

I want to load a model and for update
equivalent sql :

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 'id' FOR UPDATE;
COMMIT;
```

May magento model have the same method ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')`. The documentation for it such as it is [here](https://magento.com/resources/technical).

**OR**

Look at `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php`

This model allow to add another Models as objects in transaction. During save it call `$object->save()` for each added object.

If something fails, it call `$object->getResource()->rollBack()` for each object.

You also can add commit callbacks via `addCommitCallback(array($object, 'callbackFunctionName'))`.

If you need `delete transaction`, call `$transaction->delete()` instead of `$transaction->save()` In this case it call `$object->delete()` instead of `$object->save()` for each object.

Example:

```
try {
    $transaction = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                           ->addObject(Mage::getModel('modulename/table1'))
                           ->addObject(Mage::getModel('modulename/table2'))
                           ->addObject(Mage::getModel('modulename/table3'));

    $transaction->save();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```